# Ruby on Rails: having two xmlbuilder templates per action , one for errors one for regular output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

What's the best way to handle having two templates (or should it be one, DRY?) for xml builder templates?

I'm building a web api with Rails and wanted to see an example of how to have a view that does regular output vs one that does error output. I've been using @obj.to_xml for a while, but my requirements have changed and require me building my own error templates.

do you typically have both views in one with a condition above for errors such as

app/views/myresource/create.xml.builder

unless @myobj.errors.empty?
  // xml for errors here?
end

Can someone show me an xml.builder view example that has a case handled for when there is an error with an ActiveRecord object and or when it's successful?

// regular xml view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
 def create
   ....
   return render :template=>'error' unless @myobj.errors.empty?
   ....
   other code
 end
```

in this case rails will render error template (it can be shared across all project) if you have an error, and render create builder if there is no error.